# "Data type mismatch in criteria expression"

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to get data that are equals to and between 2 dates that i type into my textbox! The column of PO_Date is of DateTime. It works perfectly when i hard code the dates into the select statement, for example `PO_Date >= #12/6/2013 3:54:15 PM# AND PO_Date <= #1/1/2015 3:54:15 PM#` inclusive of the DropDownList2. The error only comes once i try to implement the `txtStartDate.Text` and `txtEndDate.Text`! Help is very much appreciated!

```
oRs.Open("SELECT PO_Date, PO.Vendor FROM PO 
WHERE PO_Date >= '#" & TxtStartDate.Text & "00:00:00 AM""#' AND
PO_Date <= '#" & TxtEndDate.Text & "00:00:00 AM""#' 
AND Vendor Like '%" & DropDownList2.SelectedValue & "%'", oCnn)
```

Comment: Not sure this is your problem but I would think you need a space before the `00:00:00 AM`  Like `TxtEndDate.Text & " 00:00:00 AM""#`

Comment: @Fred There wasn't a difference unfortunately

Comment: I'm typing 1/1/2013 and 1/1/2015 by the way!

Comment: Try assigning your query to a variable then looking at the value of that variable.  `strSQL = "SELECT PO_Date, PO.Vendor FROM PO 
WHERE PO_Date >= #" & TxtStartDate.Text & " 00:00:00 AM# AND
PO_Date <= #" & TxtEndDate.Text & " 00:00:00 AM# 
AND Vendor Like '%" & DropDownList2.SelectedValue & "%'"` you may see where the query is incorrect

Comment: @Fred The current problem has already been solved but this was literally my next problem haha! I've tried to store a query into a string  `Dim query As String = "SELECT ....."` but when i try to output whats in the variable "query", it just shows the entire select statement!

Comment: That would be correct.  What it will do is show you the select statement with the values from the text boxes in place.  You can then use `oRs.Open(query, oCnn)`.  It makes debugging easier.  You can also copy the entire select statement and run it against the database to see if it is correct and what it actually returns.

Comment: FYI the error message is a catchall and can usually be read as "syntax error."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you have typo, but you can check:

```
oRs.Open("SELECT PO_Date, PO.Vendor FROM PO 
WHERE PO_Date >= #" & TxtStartDate.Text & " 00:00:00 AM# AND
PO_Date <= #" & TxtEndDate.Text & " 00:00:00 AM# 
AND Vendor Like '%" & DropDownList2.SelectedValue & "%'", oCnn)
```

- `AM""#' => AM#`
- `"00:00:00 => " 00:00:00`

Comment: @MelissaS.Christ, can you check now?

Comment: It's working perfectly now! Thank you so much Giorgi!